# Configurar modulo GPRS

Tags: arduino, gps

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que tem como objetivo pegar a localização do GPS e mandar via GPRS para o servidor. Porém eu quero saber como configurar o APN para que possa ser aceito chip de qualquer operadora no modulo GPRS?

```
 while ( start_GPS() == 0);

while (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 2000) == 0);

// sets APN , user name and password
sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"", "OK", 2000);
sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"*******\"", "OK", 2000);
sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"USER\",\"*******\"", "OK", 2000);
sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"PWD\",\"*******\"", "OK", 2000);

// gets the GPRS bearer
while (sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=1,1", "OK", 20000) == 0)
{
    delay(5000);
}

delay(1000);
while(Serial.available() != 0)
{
  Serial.read();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer, é você identificar o modelo exato do seu módulo GPS e no google encontrar o pdf datasheet dele. O datasheet é um manual técnico que contém todas as especificações, exemplos de utilização e neste caso uma lista de comandos AT disponíveis. Caso você queira uma resposta mais específica, adicione também qual o modelo de seu módulo GPS na pergunta, espero ter ajudado.